# .htaccess url rewrite for a specific url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a pattern like,

`www.example.com/api.php/1`,

how do I remove .php from this url,

currently I have this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But it only works if I put `www.example.com/api` in browser,
not for `www.example.com/api/1`
not even for `www.example.com/api/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)(/.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)(/.*)?$ $1.php [NC,L]` worked for me.

Comment: Please use `$1.php$2` as I suggested otherwise php file would miss `PATH_INFO`